# How to set the shortcode of emoji in textarea with emoji mart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, emoji

My project is in javascript. I just saw the emoji mart and I created an emoji picker in react and then transpiling and injecting into my application. I was rendering properly as expected. Now, I have an issue like on click of emoji in emoji mart how I can set that emoji to my text area. please help me. below I attached a screen shot.

[image: screenshot for emoji popup]

Comment: I suppose your emoji are images in this case just add an inline `<img>` in your resulting text. (or like discord/github add something like :smiley: which is replaced by an image when rendering)

Comment: which information do you get when you click on an emoji in the mart? Having a code snippets will help us to help you

Answer (score 1):

you can simple it with native

```
addEmoji = emoji => {
  this.setState({
     content: `${this.state.content}${emoji.native}`
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made it by following this tutorial https://medium.com/@allegra9/add-emoji-picker-to-your-react-chat-app-30d8cbe8d9a6.

This is how it looks like:

```
addEmoji = e => {
    console.log(e)
    let sym = e.unified.split('-');
    let codesArray = [];

    sym.forEach(el => codesArray.push('0x' + el));
     //console.log(codesArray)  // ["0x1f3f3", "0xfe0f"]
    let emojiPic = String.fromCodePoint(...codesArray); //("0x1f3f3", "0xfe0f")

    this.setState({
         content: `${this.state.content}${emojiPic}`
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
const [input, setInput] = useState("");
<Picker set="apple" emojiSize={34} showPreview={false} color={"#009688"} onSelect={emoji => setInput(input + emoji.native)}
<form>
    <input value={input} onChange={e => setInput(e.target.value)} placeholder="Type a message" type="text"/>
    <button onClick={sendMessage} type="submit"> Send a message</button>
</form>
```